# phpdoc standard for setting default value of an optional parameter?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Example:

```
/**
 * This function will determine whether or not one string starts with another string.
 * @param string $haystack <p>The string that needs to be checked.</p>
 * @param string $needle <p>The string that is being checked for.</p>
 * @param boolean $case[optional] <p>Set to false to ignore case(capital or normal characters)</p>
 * @return boolean <p>If the $haystack string does start with the $needle string, the return will be true. False if not.</p>
 */
function endsWith($haystack,$needle,$case=true) {
    if($case){return (strcmp(substr($haystack, strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)),$needle)===0);}
    return (strcasecmp(substr($haystack, strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)),$needle)===0);
}
```

The optional parameter is set to `true` by default. I wish to indicate what the default setting is in the documentation. Is there a standard way of doing this or do I have to mention it in the description?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The doc says](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html):

> Note that the $paramname,... will be
>   shown in the output docs in both the
>   parameter listing AND the function
>   signature. If you are not indicating
>   in the actual code that the parameter
>   is optional (via "$paramname = 'a
>   default value'"), then you should
>   mention in the parameter's description
>   that the parameter is optional.

So if you're not showing the default assignment in the function signature, it would be a good idea to include it in the description, but in your case you *are* including it in the signature. So, you don't need to change a thing unless doing so would make you feel better.

Comment: Thanks. And it does make me feel somewhat better, yes :)

Comment: This is the answer in case when an optional param is included in function signature. But what if it is not? How to document an optional parameter? As from docs the only way is to tell it in description. So there is no way to write for example `[$case=true]`. Even jsdoc has it.